# Unmatched closing ')' pattern exception

Tags: java, regex

I have this regular expression:

```
"\\(d+)(,)\\(w+)(,)\\(w+)(,)\\(w+)(,)\\(\")(d+)(,)(d+)(.)(d+)(\")(,)\\(w+)(,)\\(w+)(,)\\(w+)";
```

and I'm getting this message:

> Unmatched closing ')' near index 3

Can someone please give me a hint as to what's wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: \\ escapes the metacharacter ( so you end up having ) with no matching (

Comment: what are you actually trying to match? Something like this `\ddd,\www,\www,\www,\"ddd,ddd,ddd",\www,\www,\www`? or maybe this `\123,\word,\word,\word,\"123,123,123",\word,\word,\word`?

Answer (score 3):

You are escaping the first parenthesis (so its meaning will be literal) but not the next, so it is an invalid regex.

```
"\\(d+)(,)
   ^  ^
   |  |
    --+- // You have escaped this one...
      |
       - // ...but not this one.
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `\\(d+)` you probably wanted `(\\d+)` or even better `\\d+`. You are getting error because `\\` affect `(` not `d`.